# Consul service gives me a 403 forbidden

Tags: wget, consul, http-status-code-503

On my server i have a function that does a "wget whatsmyip.com" and this is working just fine. Now i need to be using consul. So I registered a consul service called "myip". When i do a "wget myip" I see that my server is connecting to the right ip adress and port but i get a 403 forbidden request.
nano

This is my service

```
    "ID": "myip",
    "Name": "myip",
    "Address": "whatsmyip.com",
    "Port": 7586
}
```

This is the response

```
[lil ~]$ wget myip
--2019-08-12 07:52:08--  http://myip/
Resolving myip (myip)... 104.31.83.52, 104.31.82.52, 104.31.83.52, ...
Connecting to myip (myip)|104.31.83.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2019-08-12 07:52:08 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, they allow only certain clients, if I add a client header to the request, this affects the reply:

```
# curl -I --header  "User-Agent: insomnia/6.5.4"  https://www.whatismyip.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 06:29:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


# curl -I --header  "User-Agent: wget"  https://www.whatismyip.com
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 06:29:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
```

Of course I don't have access to check what clients they do or don't allow, but this way you can make your stuff work.